# C/Pointer - Declaring a local variable pointer without initializing it

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, segmentation-fault

So, I tried doing something like this :

```
void place(struct node * list, int elem){                                                                                                                                                         
    struct node *tmp = list;                                                                                                                                                                      
    struct node *prev ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    while(tmp && tmp->info <= elem){                                                                                                                                                              
        prev = tmp;                                                                                                                                                                               
        tmp = tmp->next;                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                             
    struct node *new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));                                                                                                                                
    new->info = elem;                                                                                                                                                                             
    new->next = prev->next;                                                                                                                                                                       
    prev->next = new;                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

And it gave me a segmentation fault. gdb didn't help - showed a backtrace full of 000000 and ??.

But when I tried this :

```
void place(struct node * list, int elem){                                                                                                                                                         
    struct node *tmp = list;                                                                                                                                                                      
    struct node *prev = tmp;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    while(tmp && tmp->info <= elem){                                                                                                                                                              
        prev = tmp;                                                                                                                                                                               
        tmp = tmp->next;                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                             
    struct node *new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));                                                                                                                                
    new->info = elem;                                                                                                                                                                             
    new->next = prev->next;                                                                                                                                                                       
    prev->next = new;                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

It worked fine ! The only difference between the two is that I'm initializing the local variable pointer prev in the second case, while I'm not doing so in the first case. But I can't see why the first case should be a segmentation fault ?

Can someone please explain this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider what happens if the `while()` condition is false when it's first encountered.  `prev` will never be assigned anything sensible.

Answer (score 4):

If your while loop fails, prev is never assigned a value and therefore the prev->next value is undefined.  Assigning the tmp into prev fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy. `tmp && tmp->info <= elem` could be `false` on the first iteration and `new->next = prev->next;` would raise a segmentation fault, because `prev` variable is not initialized

Answer (score 1):

This would not compile in neither C nor C++.

- If you compiled in C, you wouldn't be able to declare a variable below the while loop.
- If you compiled in C++, you would get a syntax error for using the "new" keyword.

Turns out you are using a non-standard compiler. You should get one that conforms to either the ISO C or the ISO C++ standard!

Comment: Nice - I'm using gcc 4.4.3 - maybe I've to enable C99 syntax checking in it for it to conform to what you're saying, it seems to be a little lax right now :)